# How to generate Sales order with serial number item without stock availability in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, account, erp, inventory-management

We are using the NetSuite Advance inventory module and Serialize Inventory. I need to generate a Sales order with Serial number Item before generating Purchase Order. Is it possible?

Please share your thought on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem generating the sales order. You will need to have a serialized item to choose from when you fulfill the order.